# Prove/Disprove that $f$ is unbounded?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Prove/disprove:
If $f:\left(a,b\right)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $sup_{x\in \left(a,b\right)}\left|f\:'\left(x\right)\right|\:=\:\infty $ then $f$ is unbounded at $(a,b)$.

What is the meaning of $sup_{x\in \left(a,b\right)}\left|f\:'\left(x\right)\right|\:=\:\infty $? that $f'(x)$ is unbounded? and how does it help to question?

Comment: If $\sup_{x \in (a,b)} |f'(x)| = \infty$ that means the magnitude of the derivative can be arbitrarily large at points $x$ in the open interval $(a,b)$.  That is, for any arbitrarily large value $M>0$, we can find an $x \in (a,b)$ such that $|f'(x)|\geq M$.

Comment: So this question wants you to think about the following:  If the derivative of a function can have arbitrarily large magnitude, does that mean the function itself must have arbitrarily large magnitude?   (Yes or no, and why)